# Can't intercept collect call with Aspects

Tags: java, mapreduce, aspectj

I am trying to use AspectJ with an MapReduce example, although I am not understanding one thing. But first, let me give you the code that I have.

[1] Wordcount example

```
package org.apache.hadoop.mapred.examples;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


/**
 * Common Wordcount example
 */
public class WordCount {


    public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        String line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
            output.collect(word, one);
        }
    }
}

public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        int sum = 0;
        while (values.hasNext()) {
            sum += values.next().get();
        }
        output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JobConf conf = new JobConf(WordCount.class);
    conf.setJobName("wordcount");

    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
    conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
    conf.setNumReduceTasks(2);

    conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
    conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

    JobClient.runJob(conf);
    }
}
```

[2] My mapreduce aspects

```
package org.apache.hadoop.mapred.aspects;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class MapReduceAspects {
    @Before("execution(* map(..))")
    public void mymap(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println("My Map Execution: " + joinPoint.getArgs() +   ":" + joinPoint.getTarget());
        Object[] obj = joinPoint.getArgs();
        for (Object o : obj){
           System.out.println(o.toString());
        }
    }

@Before("execution(* reduce(..))")
  public void myreduce() { System.out.println("My Reduce Execution"); }


  @Before("execution(* collect(..))")
  public void updatehash(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
      System.out.println("Output collect: Args: " + joinPoint.getArgs());

  }
}
```

```

[3] bean-aspects.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd">

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true">
    <aop:include name="mapreduceAspect"/>
</aop:aspectj-autoproxy>

<bean id="mapreduceAspect" class="org.apache.hadoop.mapred.aspects.MapReduceAspects"/></beans>
```

[4] OutputCollector interface

```
package org.apache.hadoop.mapred;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.classification.InterfaceAudience.Public;
import org.apache.hadoop.classification.InterfaceStability.Stable;

@Public
@Stable
public interface OutputCollector<K, V> {
   void collect(K var1, V var2) throws IOException;
}
```

In [1], I have an wordcount example with `map` and `reduce` function. When I launch my application in the MapReduce framework, the framework will create a job that will execute the `map` and `reduce` functions. The `map` function accepts an input dir, and the `reduce` function outputs the result.

I can intercept the `map` and `reduce` function calls with AspectJ, but I can't intercept  the `collect` call in the instruction `output.collect(word, one)` that is in the `map` function. Why this happens? Is it because the  `collect` method in the interface does not have annotation[4]? Or didn`t I configure the Aspects correctly?

I would love if anyone could explain me why AspectJ is behaving like this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple:

- The `map` and `reduce` methods are within your own code, i.e. they are subject to aspect weaving for `execution()` pointcuts.
- The `collect` method is in a 3rd party library which is not subject to aspect weaving under normal circumstances. Thus, you cannot intercept it with an `execution()` pointcut, only with a `call()` pointcut.
- Try something like `call(* collect(..))` and it will work.
- Caveat: Spring AOP does not support `call()` pointcuts, you have to use full-blown AspectJ in order to use it. See Spring manual, chapter [10.8 Using AspectJ with Spring applications](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj) for more information about how to activate AspectJ LTW (load-time weaving).
- If you use full AspectJ via LTW or binary CTW (compile-time weaving), it is also possible to weave 3rd party code and use `execution()` pointcuts. You just need to make sure that the weaving agent is loaded before any targeted 3rd party code, which is usually the case because that is what Java agents were invented for.